# Form values do not get transferred to HttpPost from View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Deposit()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Deposit(DepositTicket dt)
    {
        using (var db = new MatchGamingEntities())
        {
            MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
            Guid UserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
            var AccountId = from a in db.Accounts
                            where a.UserId == UserId
                            select a.AccountId;
            BankTransaction transaction = new BankTransaction();
            transaction.Amount = dt.Amount;
            transaction.AccountId = AccountId.SingleOrDefault();
            transaction.Created = DateTime.Today;
            transaction.TransactionType = "Credit";
            Debug.Write("Amount: " + transaction.Amount + " AccountId " + transaction.AccountId);
            db.BankTransactions.AddObject(transaction);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }

    }
```

Here is my View:

```
@model MatchGaming.Models.DepositTicket

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Deposit";
}

<h2>Deposit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>DepositTicket</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount)
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

For some reason in my HttpPost the DepositTicket dt.Amount is returning 0 even though I put a number in the form and submit, I printed the number out and its always 0.  I dont think the post variables are going through.

EDIT:

DepostTicket Class:

```
public class DepositTicket
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Deposit Amount")]
    [Range(5.00, 999999999999999999999999999.0, ErrorMessage = "Price must be above $5")]
    public decimal Amount;
}
```

EDIT 2:

Here is the rendered html

```
<form action="/Cashier/Deposit" method="post">    <fieldset>

    <legend>DepositTicket</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">

        <label for="Amount">Amount</label>

    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">

        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Decimal must be a number." data-val-required="The Decimal field is required." id="Amount" name="Amount" type="text" value="" />

        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Amount" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

        </div>

    <p>

        <input type="submit" value="Create" />

    </p>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Do you have a custom datatype declared for the amount property? Can you show the code for the DepositTicket class, that may be helpful.

Comment: Did you examine in Fiddler/Firebug on what the Http Post looked like? Does the naming convention in Model match the View?

Comment: Also note you're missing the </div> closing tag for the <div class="editor-field"> one

Comment: Thanks for quick response guys, I posted the DepositTicket class

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML that is rendered in the browser?

Comment: @Ryan O'Neill I posted the rendered html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values that are supposed to be binded using model binder have to be properties in model

```
public class DepositTicket
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Deposit Amount")]
    [Range(5.00, 999999999999999999999999999.0, ErrorMessage = "Price must be above $5")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```